# How to implement Seekbar for a video player playing FFmpeg pipe output in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg, ijkplayer

I was about to create a video player that can play FFmpeg pipe output in flutter. Luckily i found a solution with Github project flutter-ffmpeg, Thanks @tanersener for this amazing project https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg

Below I am mentioning the comment that helped me to achieve the feature i was looking for

https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg/issues/92#issuecomment-606051974

thanks, @reeckset also.

BTW, my current issue is, that I didn't find any solution on how to seek my video player that plays a pipe output of ffmpeg. Is there anything I can do for implementing a Seekbar in my video player

Comment: Do you need to seek (random access) or do you just need to update the bar? For the former, `ffmpeg` is a transcoder not a player (that's why the dev team created `ffprobe`). As such, afaik there is no internal mechanism to reposition its input streams. Your only option is to kill & restart ffmpeg when seek request is issued. For the latter, you can use `-progress` option to get the current elapsed time.

Comment: @kesh, Thanks for your response, I was actually trying that way also. I used flutter ijk player https://github.com/befovy/fijkplayer for play pipe output in fluter.And whenever there is a seekBar event i just update my ffmpeg command for seek and set that as ijkplayer data source.But in ijk player , whenever set data source it show a black screen before loading the video and that will cause horrible flickering effect in video player seek, Because i am updating video player along with seekbar not after seek.